# Cross platform build with SBT

Tags: build, sbt, cross-platform, sbt-native-packager

I'm currently testing out SBT Native Packager and my desired result is to have a native installer for each supported platform. Obviously to do this the platform specific SBT tasks will need to run on that platform.

The build will either be done with Atlassian's Bamboo or JetBrains' Team City.

Ideally I would only do the compilation and tests once and reuse the same artifacts for the packaging tasks.

What is a good way to approach this with SBT?

One way I can think of is to do the compile and test on any platform and then publish these to a local repository. Then the package would use these somehow. However this would also require changing the packaging so that it doesn't depend on the compile task etc.

Comment: "Obviously to do this the platform specific SBT tasks will need to run on that platform." It's absolutely not obvious, it's a typical limitation of numerous packager including "javapackager" used under the hood by SBT Native Packager but my own Java-based packager can create native OS X bundles under Windows, GNU Linux DEB & RPM under Mac OS X and Windows executable installers under GNU Linux: http://tuer.sourceforge.net/en/documentation/#jndt For example, it's possible to do some continuous integration under GNU Linux while targeting Windows and OS X. You can call JNDT with ant4sbt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR version**: use separate sbt projects.

As you probably noted, the [`JDKPackager`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/jdkpackager.html) plugin creates native packages on the various platforms. The trick to building and testing the primary artifacts once is to  publish them to an artifact server, and then have a separate project for creating the installer.

If you your project only needs one installer per platform, then all you should need to do is add the dependency, set the `mainClass` key, and add `enablePlugins(JDKPackagerPlugin)`:

```scala
enablePlugins(JDKPackagerPlugin)

name := "JDKPackagerPlugin Example"

version := "0.1.0"

organization := "com.foo.bar"

libraryDependencies += "com.foo.bar" %% "myProject" % "0.1.0"

mainClass in Compile := Some("com.foo.bar.ExampleApp")

// Optional: provide application file associations
jdkPackagerAssociations := Seq(
    FileAssociation("foobar", "application/foobar", "Foobar file type"),
    FileAssociation("barbaz", "application/barbaz", "Barbaz file type", jdkAppIcon.value)
)
```

If you have a scenario where you need multiple installers per platform (e.g. command-line tools vs. GUI), I typically structure a project to have a subdirectory called "packaging" with a stand-alone `build.xml` file, aggregating separate sub-projects defining each installer configuration:

```scala
// Settings common across subprojects. Could also do this with a 
// project-specific `AutoPlugin`
val baseSettings = Seq(
    libraryDependencies += "com.foo.bar" %% "myProject" % "0.1.0"
)

// The packaging aggregation project
lazy val packaging = project
   .in(file("."))
   .aggregate(a, b)

// Project with CLI configuration
lazy val a = Project(id = "my-project-cli", base = file("my-project-cli"))
  .settings(baseSettings: _*)

// Project with GUI configuration    
lazy val b = Project(id = "my-project-gui", base = file("my-project-gui"))
  .settings(baseSettings: _*)

// Create a task for invoking the sub-projects as needed
val packageSubs = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Build packages in subprojects")
(packageSubs in packaging) := {
  Seq(
    (packageBin.in(a, Universal)).value,
    (packageBin.in(b, JDKPackager)).value
  ) 
}
```

I find breaking up the installer configurations like this helps keep straight the dependencies, and effects of specific customizations.

Comment: This was a really awesome solution until I started using IntelliJ. Now it always fails to load packaging unless I do I publish after every commit.

Comment: Is it an issue with having a `.dependsOn(...)` specified? as in `a.dependsOn(b)`. I use IntelliJ too, and haven't had a problem.

Comment: Actually what I have is a little different. I have `a` and `b` produce JARs that my first build plan will produce and publish. I then have separate platform specific builds that calls `packaging/rpm:packageBin` etc. which have the artifacts from `a` and `b` as dependencies. So `packaging/update` will fail unless `a` and `b` have been published.

Comment: I got fed up with this and dug into the IntelliJ SBT source and eventually found this [sbt-ide-settings](https://github.com/JetBrains/sbt-ide-settings). Adding `ideSkipProject := true` to the packaging project works perfectly.