# Extending "universal" configuration in sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm working with sbt 0.13.8 and sbt-native-packager 1.0.3.

I'd like to to set up a development and production packaging configuration with different java options. The idea is creating a package tarball through `UniversalPluguin` from `sbt-native-packager : "universal:packageZipTarball"`. I'm also using the "`JavaServerAppPackaging`" archetype.

I tried this `Build.scala`:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaServerAppPackaging

object Build extends Build {

  lazy val commonSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.7"),
    scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq( "-unchecked", "-feature", "-language:postfixOps", "-deprecation" )
  )

  lazy val devConfig = config("dev") extend Universal
  lazy val prodConfig = config("prod") extend Universal

  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .settings(commonSettings : _*)
    .enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
    .configs(devConfig, prodConfig)
    .settings(
      javaOptions in devConfig ++= Seq(
        // -J params will be added as jvm parameters
        "-J-Xmx384m",
        "-J-Xss512k"),
      javaOptions in prodConfig ++= Seq(
        // -J params will be added as jvm parameters
        "-J-Xmx384m",
        "-J-Xss740k")
    )
}
```

With that setup, SBT keeps failing with:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbtConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.text.ParseException: unknown configuration 'universal'. It is extended by dev in null
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

See complete log in /Users/ivan/Library/Logs/IdeaIC14/sbt.last.log
```

I'm behind the idea of creating two packaged tarball for development with sbt command "`dev:packageZipTarball`", and for production with "`prod:packageZipTarball`" with different jvm options.

Any ideas why I can't extend "`universal`" configuration with custom configurations in order to achieve that or alternatives to that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend against extending *configurations*. The behaviour is not the expected one. The best way to achieve different build configurations is to create *submodules* for each configuration.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071612/cross-platform-build-with-sbt) that explains in more detail how to create subprojects with different configurations.

Comment: Great advice!. Now I'm able to execute `dev/universal:packageZipTarball` or `prod/universal:packageZipTarball` and it's working like a charm. Thanks @Muki

Comment: In my case, I have a complex application made of 75 modules and a lot of legacy code that I cannot easily split into separate modules. In my case, I have to find a way to make it work somehow.
So, despite your arguments and recommendations make a lot of sense, they cannot help in my case.

Comment: Of course you can use configuration scopes, but they are less intuitive and harder to debug.