# How to disable the update check for a specific sbt project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have a sbt build which consists of sub projects and a packaging project as described in [Cross platform build with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071612/cross-platform-build-with-sbt).

This was working fine until I started using IntelliJ since that tries to resolve the dependencies when loading the projects.

Is there any way to configure IntelliJ to not run update on a specific sbt project?

Comment: Do you have the dependencies synced locally?

Comment: The dependencies will not exist at this point since the sub projects have not been published. The workaround is to manually publish every time but this is really frustrating since the version comes from the git hash so it changed on every commit.

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting the auto import option should inform Intellij not to import dependencies unless you explicitly request an import.

From "Adding and refreshing a dependency in SBT project" in [Getting Started with SBT](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-sbt.html):

> If you didn't choose Use auto-import option then after you have added
>   your dependency in the build.sbt file, press Refresh all SBT projects
>   button in the SBT tool window to import the dependency. Note that you
>   will also see the pop-up message suggesting to enable the auto-import
>   option.

Solving your frustrations should be as simple as disabling the auto import of dependencies.

Comment: I guess that will have to do. I was hoping there was some way to be more specific and disable auto import for a sub project.

Comment: There is a [discussion in the Jetbrains community](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5566100) about slow dependency refreshing. Apparently a newer version of the Scala plugin can help.

Comment: This solution wouldn't work if we made publish depend on successful test results. Using TDD all the tests would fail to start with so the sub projects couldn't be published and now the refresh all will fail.